# Sequential numbers not continuing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sequence of 13 numbers which represent the maximum value of sequential numbers.

The code generates the first set of numbers and doesn't continue.

```vb
For x = 1 To depthRngLastRow
    maxcnt = workingWs.Range("H" & x).Value
    For i = 1 To maxcnt
        stageWs.Range("L" & i).Value = i
    Next i
Next x
Debug.Print depthRngLastRow
```

- For `x = 1`, `maxcnt = 122`. In column L in sheet `stageWs`, I get numbers from 1 to 122. This is expected.
- For `x = 2`, `maxcnt = 8`. I expect the numbering to restart from 1 to 8. This is not the case.

Comment: I apologize as I don't think I understand your question/issue.  Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding:   You would like to iterate from first cell to last cell and number `1 to X` while going down the list of cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting values:

```
For i = 1 To maxcnt
    stageWs.Range("L" & i).Value = i
Next i
```

This writes rows 1 to 122 on the first iteration of the outer loop, then overwrites rows 1 to 8 on the second iteration of the outer loop.

An alternative:

```
For i = 1 To maxcnt
    Dim count As Long
    count = count + 1
    stageWs.Range("L" & count).Value = i
Next i
```